# sorting a dictionary within a list so it outputs the scores in order of highest to lowest

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

related to a previous question, I have a dictionary within a list which I need to sort. The code is:

```
dict1 = [{"Name":"Ron","one":3,"two":6,"three":10}
     ,{"Name":"Mac","one":5,"two":8,"three":0}
     ,{"Name":"DUDE","one":16,"two":9,"three":2}]
```

I would like to so when I print out the dictionary, it will print out the name of the person with the highest score, then the name of the person with the second highest score, then the name with the third highest score etc.
The intended output for this particular list is:
DUDE 16 #as DUDE's highest score is 16, and 16 is the highest high score
Ron 10 #as Ron's highest score is 10, but it is the second highest high score
Mac 8#as Mac's highest score is 8, but his high score is the least highest high score out of the three of them.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so there will be only three scores and every one will have three scores

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath list of dictionaries and he just wants to print them

Comment: No, I would like code which would output the name of the person with the highest score, then the person with the second highest score and so on. So in this instance, I would need it to output:         DUDE 16, Ron 10, Mac 8. As DUDE's highest score is 16, that will be the score that will count and the same for every other person. I understand this problem probably has a very simple solution, but as I've looked at solutions, ive found it very complicated and confusing.

Comment: My first (now deleted) comment might be a bit unfair: this very much feels like a duplicate but the difference is that you want to look at either multiple keys or possibly arbritary keys (I still haven't seen an answer on whether there were be exactly 3 scores; please explain that).  You mention related to a previous question; you should link to that and also show what you've tried.  Also @KarolyHorvath the fact that it's a list of is very relevant; the fact that python dictionaries aren't sorted is actually more irrelevant to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?:

```
print [(x["Name"] + " " + str(max(x["one"],x["two"],x["three"])) ) for x in sorted(dict1, key=lambda row: max(row["one"],row["two"],row["three"]),reverse=True )]

>>> ['DUDE 16', 'Ron 10', 'Mac 8']
```

This essentially uses the maximum of all three values as a sorting key, and places them in reverse.  Then it prints out the name and this maximum value in a list comprehension statement.